# Drag and drop incompatible with scrolling in Firefox using touchscreen

Tags: firefox, touchscreen, scrolling, drag-and-drop

I have been testing my touchscreen to perform some operations on web browsers and we are running into an issue. When we don't change the MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 then the drag and drop works but it doesn't scroll via touch screen. Whereas when we set the variable to that value the scrolling works but the drag and drop stops working via touchscreen. We've also tried with other browsers ending with the same result.

Any ideas?